# Reset counter after finishing iterating with the array elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, counter

I’m doing this code but I can’t find the proper way to reset the counter after iterating with all the elements inside the array.

The idea is that after getting to the last song in the playlist you will get into the first one. Here is my code, i would really appreciate your help with this. Thanks in advance!

```
class Playlist
  attr_accessor :songs
  def initialize (name,songs)
    @name = name
    @songs = songs
  end

  def display_name
    @name
  end

  def number_of_songs
    "There are #{@songs.count} songs in the #{display_name}"
  end

  def add_song(song)
    @songs << song
    @songs
  end

  def next_song
    i = 0
    while i != 9
      p "Playing song: #{@songs[i]}"
      p "skip song? (Y/N)"
      user_input = gets.chomp
      if user_input.downcase == "y" && i != 8
        i += 1
      elsif user_input.downcase == "n" && i != 8
        puts "Playing song"
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        puts
        puts
        i+=1
      end
    end
  end
end

playlist = Playlist.new("The Ultimate Playlist",["In My Life","Naive","She Moves In Her Own Way","Skinny Love","All My Life","All The Small Things","Real"])

p playlist.display_name
p playlist.number_of_songs
p playlist.add_song("California(Here We Come)")
puts
p playlist.next_song
```

Comment: If you have an array, say `a=(1..10).to_a` instead of iterating, you could just rotate the array `a.rotate!` then always play `a[0]`

Answer (score 0):

After going to class i found a solution to this. that was simple to implement yet i know there are better options to solve the problem.
thank you all for the help! :D

PD: comment other solutions that you found if you'd like to

```
class Playlist
  attr_accessor :songs
  def initialize (name,songs)
    @name = name
    @songs = songs
  end

  def display_name
    @name
  end

  def number_of_songs
    "There are #{@songs.count} songs in the #{display_name}"
  end

  def add_song(song)
    @songs << song
    @songs
  end

  def next_song
    max =@songs.length
    i = 0
    finish = ""
    puts "Write Play to start the playlist (#{@name})"
    puts
    promt =">"
    print promt
    while finish.downcase != "play"
      finish = gets.chomp
      i = 0
      puts
    while i <max
      p "Playing song: #{@songs[i]}"
      p "skip song? (Y/N) or exit to end the playlist"
      print promt
      user_input = gets.chomp
      if user_input.downcase == "y" && i != 8
        i += 1
      elsif user_input.downcase == "n" && i != 8
        puts "Playing song"
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        sleep(1)
        print'.'
        puts
        puts
        i+=1
      elsif user_input.downcase == "exit"
        exit!
      end
    end
    puts
    p "Restarting playlist"
    puts
    puts "Write Play to start the playlist (#{@name})"
    puts
  end 
end
end

playlist = Playlist.new("The Ultimate Playlist",["In My Life","Naive","She Moves In Her Own Way","Skinny Love","All My Life","All The Small Things","Real"])

p playlist.display_name
p playlist.number_of_songs
p playlist.add_song("California(Here We Come)")
puts
p playlist.next_song
```